# Time complexity of Loops inside recursive function

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

Say theres a recursive function which runs n times and a nested for loop that runs n^2 times, what will be its time complexity O(n) or O(n^3)

For example :

```
fun(int n) {
if(n==1) return;

for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
  for(j=0;j<n;j++) 
    printf("A");

}
```

Comment: Well, what's `n*n^2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: Something is really wrong with this edit. OP describes a recursive function yet the edit removes recursion! OP, please go back and fix your question to make the code how you mean it to be.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the time complexity of  the above function is O(n^3).

look as it as for every n, the loops s will run n(n+1)/2 times and this will take place n time. So the total number of iterations will be (n^2)(n+1)/2 which is O(n^3).

Comment: The question is not valid. The answer is not valid. This is all wrong.

Comment: @EugeneSh well the question is naive but how is it be invalid? And please point out the errors so that i can correct myself in my answers. Thank you!